# SSIS - OLE DB Connection Manager is truncating numeric value when the destination is money

Tags: ssis, oledbconnection

When I load numeric column directly to a money column, OLEDB component is truncating the value in it, but TSQL and ADO.NET components are rounding as expected.

Source value : 2.081250

Vat1: map directly ,
Vat2: map after converting to money data type

```
    Result:
    VAT1    VAT2    CONN 
    2.0813  2.0813  TSQL
    2.0813  2.0813  ADO
    2.0812  2.0813  OLEDB
```

2.0812 : numeric -> money directly with OLEDB

Do you have any idea? Is it default behavior of OLEDB component?

Regards,

Mustafa

Test Case:

```
    -- Source
    CREATE TABLE TEST_NUMERIC(VAT1 NUMERIC(38,6), VAT2 NUMERIC(38,6))
    INSERT INTO TEST_NUMERIC VALUES( 2.081250, 2.081250)

    -- Destination 
    CREATE TABLE TEST_MONEY(VAT1 MONEY, VAT2 MONEY, CONN NVARCHAR(20))

    -- Test 1 - With TSQL
    INSERT INTO TEST_MONEY
    SELECT VAT1, CAST(VAT2 AS MONEY), 'TSQL' FROM TEST_NUMERIC 


    -- Test2 - With SSIS, ADO NET and OLE DB components:
    ADO.Net Source: 
    SELECT VAT1, CAST(VAT2 AS MONEY) VAT2, N'ADO' AS CONN
    FROM TEST_NUMERIC

    Ado .Net Destination: TEST_MONEY

    **OLE DB Source:** 

    SELECT VAT1, CAST(VAT2 AS MONEY) VAT2, N'OLEDB' AS CONN
    FROM TEST_NUMERIC

    OLEDB Destination: TEST_MONEY
```

[SSIS Package:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cKAU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum scale for `DT_CY` (SSIS data type for money) is four and OLE DB connections do support this data type, which by the data in your example (2.081250), would be 2.0812.  Since you're doing the casting within SQL Server for the V2 column, this is rounded up to 2.0813 before SSIS processes it.  The ADO equivalent of money would be decimal (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2017)).  So while you can add the money column in your ADO.NET destination and map to the the numeric data type of your source, the destination money data type is still interpreted as decimal, which preserves the longer scale, and in this case would round up to the 2.0813 value that you're seeing here.